# Panda sum rows based on metric on column value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe df of the form

```
 type  | time   | value
------------------------
  a    |    1.2 |  1
  a    |    1.3 |  3
  a    |    2.1 |  4
  a    |    2.3 |  6
  b    |    2   |  21
  b    |    3   |  3
  .         .      .
  .         .      .
```

Is there any feasible way to, for all rows, consolidate (sum) all following rows of a given type that have a timestamp difference of less than, for example, 1? 
So for this example, the second and third row should be added to the first and the output should be

```
 type  | time   | value
------------------------
  a    |    1.2 |  8
  a    |    2.3 |  6
  b    |    2   |  21
  b    |    3   |  3
  .         .      .
  .         .      .
```

Normally I would simply iterate over every row, add the value for all following rows that satisfy the constraint to the active row and then drop all rows whose values were added from the dataframe. But I'm not completely sure how to do that safely with panda considering that "You should never modify something you are iterating over."
But I sadly also don't see how this could be done with any operation that is applied on the whole dataframe at once.

Edit: I've found a very rough way to do it using a while loop. In every iteration it only adds the next row to those rows that already have no row of the same type with a time stamp less than 1 before it:

```
df['nexttime']= df['time'].shift(-1)
df['nexttype']= df['type'].shift(-1)
df['lasttime']= df['time'].shift(1)
df['lasttype']= df['type'].shift(1)
df['nextvalue'] = df['value'].shift(-1)

while df.loc[(df.type == df.nexttype) & ((df.time - df.lasttime >1) | (df.type != df.lasttype)) &  (df.time - df.nexttime <=1 ),'value'].any():
    df.loc[(df.type == df.nexttype) & ((df.time - df.lasttime >1 ) | (df.type != df.lasttype)) &  (df.time - df.nexttime <=1  ),'value'] = df.loc[(df.type == df.nexttype) & ((df.time - df.lasttime >1 ) | (df.type != df.lasttype)) &  (df.time - df.nexttime <=1  ),'value'] + df.loc[(df.type == df.nexttype) & ((df.time - df.lasttime >1 ) | (df.type != df.lasttype)) &  (df.time - df.nexttime <=1  ),'nextvalue']
    df = df.loc[~((df.shift(1).type == df.shift(1).nexttype) & ((df.shift(1).time - df.shift(1).lasttime >1 ) | (df.shift(1).type != df.shift(1).lasttype)) &  (df.shift(1).time - df.shift(1).nexttime <=1  ))]
    df['nexttime']= df['time'].shift(-1)
    df['nexttype']= df['type'].shift(-1)
    df['lasttime']= df['time'].shift(1)
    df['lasttype']= df['type'].shift(1)
    df['nextvalue'] = df['value'].shift(-1)
```

I would still be very interested if there is any faster way to do this, as this kind of loop obviously is not very efficient (especially since for the kind of dataframes I work with it has to iterate a few ten thousand times).

Comment: Can you explain how you arrive to your expected output? I'm not sure where the value of `8` for time of `1.2` is coming from

Comment: It's the sum of the values of the first 3 rows. Because starting with the first row (with time 1.2), the second and third row have a timestamp that is different by less than 1 and thus get consolidated into it). I've also edited the first post to make it more clear.

Comment: Don't they all have a difference of less than 1? When I run: `df['diff'] = df['time'].diff() ` and then filter based on `>1` using: `df2.groupby('diff').filter(lambda x: x['diff'] > 1)` I will recieve an empty dataframe. I guess it comes down to your logic on your rolling sum/difference?

Comment: That would be true (and make the whole thing alot easier) if the rows that got consolidated (besides the one row they get consolidated into) would not be dropped from the table. After the second and third row get added to the first row, they are not part of the df anymore and the first and fourth row have a different larger than 1.